# Detect user proximity from the screen

Tags: c++, blackberry-10, proximity

I'm working on a BB10 app that needs to be able to [disable the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545315/disable-screen-during-call/29545316) when the user holds the phone up to his/her face during a call.

How can I tell when the user is holding the phone up to his/her face?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect the user's proximity from the phone, you can use a [QProximitySensor](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qproximitysensor.html).

In order to use this, you need to add these lines to your project's .pro file:

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += sensors
```

Add the necessary includes to the .cpp and .h files:

```
#include <QtSensors/QProximitySensor>
using QtMobility::QProximitySensor;

#include <QtSensors/QProximityReading>
using QtMobility::QProximityReading;
```

Define the proximity sensor in the .h file. Create and destroy the sensor in your constructor and destructor functions.

When the call starts, connect your sensor's `readingChanged` function to the one that you intend to handle the reading, and activate it:

```
connect(proximitySensor, SIGNAL(readingChanged()), this, SLOT(checkReading()));
proximitySensor->setActive(true);
```

When the call ends, deactivate the sensor:

```
proximitySensor->setActive(false);
```

Finally, use the reading's `close` function to tell when the device is close to the user's face. Note that the distance defined as "close" may be different for different devices.

```
bool isClose = proximitySensor->reading()->close();
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to act upon changes to the reading, you can skip connecting the `readingChanged` signal and use the `close` function independently.