# Disable screen during call

Tags: c++, screen, qml, blackberry-10

I'm working on a BB10 app that needs to disable the screen in the same way that holding it close to your face does during a call. I implemented a proximity sensor to [detect when the screen should be disabled or enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545214/detect-user-proximity-from-the-screen/29545215), but BB10's APIs don't seem to provide a way to turn the screen on or off.

What can I use to disable and re-enable the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by adding a `Container` around the outermost `Container` in the QML file, and setting its `background` to `Color.Black`. Then added an `id` to the formerly outermost `Container` and implement an `onScreenEnabled(enabled)` function to show or hide it.

```
Container {
    background: Color.Black

    Container {
        id: callContainer

        ...
    }
}

function onScreenEnabled(enabled) {
    callContainer.visible = enabled;
}
```

In the .cpp file, use the proximity sensor's reading to emit a signal to enable or disable the screen:

```
void CallProgress::checkReading() {
    bool isClose = proximitySensor->reading()->close();
    this->SetScreenEnabled(!isClose);
}

void CallProgress::SetScreenEnabled(const bool enabled) {
    emit screenEnabled(enabled);
}
```

Add the signal and function declarations to the .h file. In the .qml file, connect the emitted signal to the corresponding QML function.

This will hide the UI whenever the proximity sensor's readings detect that the user is close to the screen.